# Find points to split n-dimensional time series based on labeled data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-extraction

I'm at the starting point of a bigger project to identify common patterns in time series.
**The goal is to automatically find split points in time series which splits the series into commonly used patterns.** (Later I want to split the time series based on the split points to use the time series in between independently.)

One time series consists of:

- n data series based on a fix time interval as input
- The x-axis represents the interval indices from 0 to m
- The y-axis represents the values of the specific time series

For example, it could look like this:

```
pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,force_x,force_y,force_z,speed,is_split_point
 2,     3,    4,  0.4232, 0.4432,    0,     0.6, false
 2,     3,    4,  0.4232, 0.4432,    0,     0.6, false
 2,     3,    4,  0.4232, 0.4432,    0,     0.6, true
```

My best bet is to solve this problem with Machine Learning because I need a general approach to detect the patterns based on the user selection beforehand.
Therefore I have a lot of labeled data where the split points are already set manually by the user.

Currently, I have two ideas to solve this problem:

1. **Analyzing the data around the split points** in the labeled data to derive a correlation between the different data dimensions and use this as new features on unlabeled data.
2. **Analyzing the patterns between two keyframes** to find similar patterns in unlabeled data.

I prefer 1. because I think it's more important to find out what defines a split point. 
I'm curious about if neuronal networks are well suited for this task?

I ask the question not to get a solution for the problem, I just want to get a second opinion on this. I'm relatively new to Machine Learning, that's why it's a bit overwhelming to find a good starting point for this problem. I'm very happy with any ideas, techniques and useful resources which could cover this problem and can give me a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Whooo that is a great queastion.
In matter of fact, I also have some ideas to give to you, some of them were tested and worked on different time-based problems with anomaly events I encountered.

First, analyzing the data is always a great approach for better understanding of the problem, regardless of what solution you will use. This way you ensure that you don't feed you models garbage. Tools for this analysis can be peaks in a truncated past window, derivatives, etc.

Then you can draw the data using [t-sne](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) and see if there is some kind of separation in the data.

However, simply using neural networks can be problematic since you have small number of split points and large number of non-split points.
You can use LSTMs and train them in a many-to-one configuration, where you create balanced number of positive and negative examples. The LSTMs will help you to overcome the varying length of the examples, and give more meaning to the time domain.

Going into that direction you can use truncated past and make it as an example with the `is_split_point` as the label, and use an i.i.d model by pulling samples in a balanced way. DNNS also works in that configuration.

All the above are experimented approaches that I found useful.
I hope it helps. GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I think that's a great path to start. t-sne looks very promising. I will work on the material and write back again.

Comment: I'm trying to build a LSTM model with Keras. Do you have any suggestions? 
`model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (None, input_dim)))`
`model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`
`model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])`